# Return 404 on Spring Boot /actuator root endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

When In production I want to disable the /actuator endpoint but still allow /actuator/health. I have tried the code below using SecurityConfigurerAdapter but its returning 500. I want to return a 404 and get a "page not found" error page. Any help is much appreciated

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        if(isProd) {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/", "/actuator").denyAll();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Spring Security.

This can be configured using properties:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

By default health and info are exposed via web.

So you could relay on the for production and in development you run your app with

```
-Dmanagement.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: Dont think you understand my question. The literal /actuator endpoint is exposed by default as well which returns the actuator endpoints that are exposed. I don't want this in production. I want is /actuator/health but not /actuator

Comment: And why do you want to do that? This will only display the links to the available endpoints